# AWS Cloudformation "include" transform error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have some template and other partial definition I'd like to include in main template definition. The sample is below (main template).

```js
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",

  "Description": "",

  "Parameters": {
    "Environment": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "Specify Environment: prod | dev ",
      "AllowedValues": [ "prod", "dev" ],
      "Default": "dev"
    }
  },
  
  "Transform": {
    "Name": "AWS::Include",
    "Parameters": {
      "Location": "s3://some-s3-local-bucket/part-1.json"
    }
  },

  "Resources": {
  },

  "Outputs": {
  }
}
```

Below is a definition of the part to include in main template

```js
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",

  "Description": "",

  "Resources": {
    "hellobucket": {
        "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
        "Properties": {
          "BucketName": { "Fn::Sub": "testbucket-${Environment}" }
        }
    }
  },

  "Outputs": {
  }
}
```

When I try to create stack based on such definitions I receive strange error like "**Template parameters modified by transform**". I don't know/see any reason any parameter could be considered as "modified".

I don't want to create many "nested" stacks, because there is a limit on aws in number of stacks I can create so the goal is to split stack definition into many (well managable) smaller files and based on them to create ONE stack with all the related resources.

**How to properly decompose bigger stack definition into smaller files?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done this before but it might be because you are using the transform to pull in a template that creates an s3 bucket BUT the template you are pulling into the original one has all it's parameter fields etc. empty.  I think this is what the error message - Template parameters modified by transform - is relating to.  Try removing the empty parameters entry from the S3 template to see if that helps.

Comment: I replaced the definition of partial template with proper content also (that one that works in my case)

Comment: Some useful link yet:  
https://thomasvachon.com/articles/making-modular-cloudformation-with-includes/